# С++, класс теста максимально доступного размера для выделения памяти

Tags: c++, память

Нужна реализация класса проверяющего в рантайме:

- Максимально доступный или оптимальный размер для выделения памяти под программу.
- Максимально доступный или оптимальный размер для выделения памяти для контейнера объектов одного типа. (количество объектов одного типа)

Comment: Что такое "оптимальный размер" в вашем понятии?

Comment: Размер с учетом других объектов, достаточно хотя бы максимальный

Answer (score 1):

Затея, имхо, довольно глуповата, но можно пробовать рекурсивно выделять/освобождать память до получения максимально возможного результата. Идея основана на том, что `new` кидает исключение `std::bad_alloc`, если выделить память запрошенного размера невозможно в данный момент.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

bool isGood(size_t size) {
    try {
        char* c = new char[size];
        delete[] c;
        return true;
    }
    catch(...) {}
    return false;
}

size_t findMax(size_t good, size_t bad) {
    const size_t test = good/2 + bad/2;
    if(test == good) return good;
    if( isGood(test) ) {
        return findMax(test, bad);
    }
    else {
        return findMax(good, test);
    }
}

size_t getMax() {
    return findMax(0, std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max());
}

int main() {
    std::cout << getMax() << "\n";
}
```

<kbd>[Результат выполнения](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/PlBQiV4kuRuSYpcK)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Тест совершенно бессмысленный - за время между последним тестом и моментом, когда память реально понадобится, ситуация может примерно миллиард раз поменяться.